# How to break out of promise after number of requests-then chain in nodejs

Tags: node.js, axios

I was trying to read a CSV file (900 000 data) and want to pass it to an POST API. But I am unable to pass the complete data as the data is huge. So I want to pause the promises after every 100k rows and make the axios call and then want to resume the promises back. So that I can reduce the load on the server.

Please correct me if something is wrong as I am very new to nodejs.

```
    async function readcsv(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let csvdata = [];
        fs.createReadStream(path)
            .on('error', () => {
                // handle error
            })
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', (row) => {
                csvdata.push([evname,uid,data])
                console.log(csvdata)
            })
            .on('end', async() => {
                resolve (csvdata)
            })
    })
}

readcsv('filename.csv').then(data => {
    let token = jwt.sign({payload:data},secrete_key)
    axios.get(`${URL}?c=${comp_id}&jwt=${token}`).then(function(res){
        console.log(res.data)
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
    })
})
```

Comment: In your code, the promise only resolves when the whole file has been read. Maybe you can parse the data when you call the `readcsv` function by manipulating `data`

Comment: Thanks @James Z for correcting me

Comment: Thanks @Aviv Lo for your suggestion even tried that but no luck